# Could not load file or asssembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

I'm porting a .Net 3.5 Console Application from vs2008 to a .Net Core Console Application in vs2017 (target framework netcoreapp1.1).

The program does some plugin loading by looking for .dlls in a given directory and loading them as assemblies.

I have rebuilt the plugins as netstandard1.6 libraries. Admittedly I'm a little confused by the differences between Core, Framework and Standard.

I am using the System.Runtime.Loader (v4.3.0) NuGet package and the following code to try and load assemblies from a given path:

```
public static Assembly LoadAssemblyFromPath(string path)
{
    AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (context, name) =>
    {
        // avoid loading *.resources dlls, because of: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/8416
        if (name.Name.EndsWith("resources"))
            return null;

        string[] foundDlls =
            Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(new FileInfo(path).FullName, name.Name + ".dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        return foundDlls.Any() ? context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(foundDlls[0]) : context.LoadFromAssemblyName(name);
    };

    return AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
}
```

I've verified the path parameter is correct, and the file exists, however I am still getting a "Could not load file or assembly" exception. The Resolving event is never raised.

Can anyone offer any insight to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the Dll you are loading also a .Net core dll? Core applications can not load DLL's that are built for the .net framework, it can only load dll's that are built for .net core or .net standard.

Comment: How can I determine that? The plugin dlls are all target framework netstandard1.6

Comment: Just as a note, since you are talking about plugins; have you considered using MEF? Here is a blog about it: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/using-mef-in-net-core

Comment: Unfortunately I need to maintain backwards compatability with the older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

```
    public static Assembly LoadAssemblyFromPath(string path)
    {
        string fileNameWithOutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

        bool inCompileLibraries = DependencyContext.Default.CompileLibraries.Any(l => l.Name.Equals(fileNameWithOutExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        bool inRuntimeLibraries = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries.Any(l => l.Name.Equals(fileNameWithOutExtension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        return inCompileLibraries || inRuntimeLibraries
            ? Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(fileNameWithOutExtension))
            : AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
    }
```